# Application Insights Analytics doing sub selects

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I am using this reference [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference) for Application Insights.

How can I do a sub-select using the output of a different query?

```
//Query 1
Events 
| where  Timestamp >= ago(30min) and Data contains('SomeString')
| project TraceToken

//I would like to use the first query's output in the subselect here.
Events 
| where TraceToken in ({I would like to use the First query's output here.})
```

Is a join better in this scenario. Which would have better performance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `let` statement to achieve this.

Here is an example from the [Analytics documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/letstatement), I hope this helps:

```
let topCities =  toscalar ( // convert single column to value
   requests
   | summarize count() by client_City 
   | top 4 by count_ 
   | summarize makeset(client_City));
requests
| where client_City in (topCities) 
| summarize count() by client_City;
```

**Edit**: By default the maximum number of elements returned by the [makeset()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/makeset-aggfunction) function is 128. The MaxSetSize should be specified for larger dataSets.

Comment: Removed my post on using a join since this answer fills the OPs question

Comment: James Davis, Can you please also post the answer with the join. I would like to do a comparison of performance and see if a specific query type suits a situation.

Comment: Dmitry, Thanks for your answer. It works great on a small Dataset. The query is timing out once I increase the date range. How can I make it more efficient for larger datasets. We have approximately half a billion Events per day.  A query over a range of half a day is timing out.

Comment: If you have a huge data set making it into TraceToken set and then each of the TraceToken in the second query goes through the whole set again and again - then you might want to use the join. `A | where <filterA> | project TraceToken | join (B | where <filterB>) | project <myFields>) on TraceToken | <ContinueQueryHere>`. The link in my answer above also contains examples of joins.