# What is the conventional way of checking whether something Exists in another table in Application Insights Analytics Query Language?

Tags: analytics, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I want to limit requests by a specific associated dependency by name. I tried using a *leftsemi* [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#join-operator) but that didn't seem to work as I expected because it game me the same results as my inner join.

```
requests
| where timestamp >= ago(24h)
| join kind=leftsemi (
    dependencies
    | where name contains "MYDATABASENAME" 
) on operation_Id 
| summarize count() by tostring(parseurl(url).Path)
| order by count_ desc
```

I'm looking at the the [where-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#where-in-operator) statement next but I'm still unsure whether this is sort of the expected way to do what what typically be an [exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) statement in T-SQL.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258994/application-insights-analytics-doing-sub-selects

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [let](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#let) statement to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in order to get the where-in semantics you should use inner join. From the documentation of [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#join-operator) (at the *kind=inner* section):

> There's a row in the output for every combination of matching rows from left and right.

In addition, since there's a limit on the size of the returned table, you might want to limit the right side of the join like this:

```
requests 
| where timestamp >= ago(24h)
| join kind=inner (
    dependencies
    | where name contains "MYDATABASENAME" 
    | project operation_Id
) on operation_Id 
| summarize count() by tostring(parseurl(url).Path)
| order by count_ desc
```